# Using Spring WebClient + ConfigServer

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-config

We are developing microservices using Spring WebClient to generate clients of another microservices. Just like you can see in the next code snippet:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

final private WebClient webClient;

@Value("${host:10.244.0.34}")
String host;

@Value("${port:80}")
String port;

@Value("${scheme:http}")
String scheme;

ModeloWebClientImpl(){
    this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT)
    .build();
}
```

When we have the hard-coded values, everything is fine.

But we have a problem here, the value of the host field is changing frequently. Given that we have a ConfigServer component deployed in our architecture, how can we use this component to get the host value? We are trying to get the host but we are receiving errors creating the bean of the service client.

Comment: *trying to get the host but we are receiving errors* - unless you post the errors and the relevant code, all we can offer is next to nothing

Comment: This is the error received - Error creating bean with name 'TargetServiceImpl' : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'targetWebClient'

Comment: So, the code above has zero relevance.